# Average formula that starts with the first non-zero value, but includes all zeros after the first

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

First post here so hopefully I do this right. I have a range of values that correspond to monthly sales. I want to take an average of the range starting in the first month sales exist, but I need to include any values that are zero after the first month as well.

I was using =sum(A1:G1)/(countif(A1:G1,"<>0")) but this will exclude all zeros and skew my average.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:G1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:G1)/(A1:G1<>0),1)):G1)
```

`INDEX(A1:G1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:G1)/(A1:G1<>0),1))` returns the first cell that is not `0` and the `G1` sets the end.

This will throw an error if no non zero entries are found so you many want to wrap it in an IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(A1:G1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:G1)/(A1:G1<>0),1)):G1),0)
```

Now if all the entries are 0 then it will return 0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment! But this formula is not returning the correct average. Perhaps I didnt explain well enough.

Example: 
Item 1: 1, 0, 4, 3, 3
Item 2: 0, 0,0, 4, 5
Item 3: 0,4,5,4,0

For Item 1, I want the average of the whole range, for item 2 I want the average of 4 and 5, and for item 3 I want to average of 4,5,4 and 0.

Comment: I got it, sorry about that, I must have had a misplaced comma or something on my first try. Thank you Scott